# WrapQuery and other Transforms

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

**I struggle to understand** `WrapQuery` constructor params. According to the documentation the signature is:

```
WrapQuery( path: Array<string>, wrapper: QueryWrapper, extractor: (result: any) => any, )
```

For `QueryWrapper` I dig deep and I have found this declaration in the code (nothing in the doc):

```
export declare type QueryWrapper = (subtree: SelectionSetNode) => SelectionNode | SelectionSetNode;
```

I have a mutation and **I want to transform input variable for this mutation** into different input variable. So far I didn't even manage the example they got in the docs to work https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms:

```js
new WrapQuery(
            ['priv_createConsumer'],
            (subtree) => { // subtree seems to contain one node only?? weird
                return {
                    kind: Kind.FIELD, // no idea which enum should I use here
                    name: {
                        kind: Kind.NAME, // no idea which enum should I use here
                        value: 'contact',
                    },
                    selectionSet: subtree,
                }
            },
            // how to process the data result at path
            (result) => { // result is mostly undefined or null (based on few things I tried to change
                return result && result.address
            }
        )
```

Comment: graphql docs are far from easy imo :/